# Android: not showing messages on onPasswordFailed

Tags: android, device-admin

I have implemented my own class, extending the **DeviceAdminReceiver**, given the app appropriate authorities to run this etc.

I have tried to display a message (as a simple Toast as below, and by starting a new activity) when user has entered wrong PIN, but I cannot get that working. The code executes as intended, but the messages are only showing up until after entering the correct PIN.

Are there any special tricks I need to do, or is this screen simply restricted in Android?

(probably I do not need to run the `super.onPasswordFailed()`, but please disregard from that now)

```
@Override
public void onPasswordFailed(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onPasswordFailed(context, intent);
    Log.i("MYAPP: ", "swDeviceAdminReceiver::onPasswordFailed");

    Toast.makeText(context, "Password failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that ´onPasswordFailed´ is firing?

Comment: Yes. But I just found an answer to my problem,using the following in my activity onCreate did the trick:                                                           Window window = getWindow();
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED)